# Adding a square to a number gives a prime

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I am interested in the following problem:

Let $n$ be a fixed positive integer. What is the approximate number of primes $n \leq p \leq n^2+n$ such that $p-n$ is a perfect square.

It is not difficult to approximate the total number of primes in the interval $[n,n^2+n]$, for example by using the prime number theorem.
However, I don't know how to locate this specific set of primes.

I assume that some sort of sieve argument might be helpful, but I do not have much experience with that, so any suggestions in this direction are very welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you found so far?

Comment: The first $100$ values are $1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 5, 1, 4, 5, 2, 5, 4, 2, 3, 9, 4, 3, 8, 3, 5, 11, 3, 4, 7, 4, 5, 6, 3, 7, 15, 3, 8, 8, 3, 8, 12, 3, 7, 8, 5, 7, 7, 4, 6, 10, 5, 5, 10, 4, 11, 25, 3, 11, 7, 6, 13, 14, 4, 7, 22, 4, 5, 15, 6, 15, 17, 4, 9, 11, 8, 19, 14, 6, 12, 19, 6, 9, 19, 6, 11, 19, 5, 9, 15, 9, 20, 11, 8, 10, 23, 9, 15, 22$.  This sequence does not (yet) seem to be in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org).  I encourage you to contribute it.

Comment: @ChrisLewis Ideally, I would hope to get at least cn such primes for large enough n. However, I have no idea how likely this is to be true.

Comment: The existence of such a prime for large $n$ is very likely. We have $n$ numbers with magnitude upto about $n^2$ and not all with have small factors. So, there is likely a prime for every sufficient large (and probably even for all $n$). But I do not think we can find a proof , usually such questions cannot be completely answered.

Comment: If $n=p$ is not allowed , $n=5$ is the only counterexample upto $10^7$. If we also rule out $p-n=1$ , still the only counterexamples upto $10^7$ are $1,2,5$

Comment: It's equivalent, and seems a bit more straightforward, to ask: take the first $n$ squares and add $n$ to each of them, obtaining $1^2+n,2^2+n,\dots,(n-1)^2+n,n^2+n$; how many of these numbers are prime? I would certainly not expect $cn$ of them to be prime—the heuristic that a number $x$ is prime "with probability $1/\log x$" suggests more like $cn/\log n$—and indeed I imagine that sieve techniques can disprove $cn$. Note that we can't even prove that there's a *single* prime of the form $m^2+n$ for arbitrary $n$, even without the size restriction on $m$...!